# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.querySelector('#rewards_modal').addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('.modal-body').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      console.log('scroll y');
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError+Cannot+read+properties+of+null+addEventListener+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also every time  you show the modal, you add an eventListener to the modal-body

Comment: At least for one of your query selectors there is no element found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script tags after the html elements it's referencing.